High math |4| |6| |=| |7| |2|
Place and move the cards in your mind's eye so that the result is correct “high math”.
$$\boxed4 \boxed6 \boxed= \boxed7 \boxed2$$
(I would also be pleased if you could give an indication of the level of difficulty for non-mathematicians, I wanted to use this puzzle at a puzzle party.)

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)! I think that what is needed on the right side of the equation would be tricky for non-mathematicians especially if they have been out of school for a long time.

Move two cards so they look like:

 $49=7^2$

 The 6 card has been rotated and the 2 card has been moved up.


Would you say the quiz pattern occurs often?

@Peterius If someone has been doing recreational math puzzles for years, they would likely have seen something similar to your puzzle.  If they haven’t done many puzzles, this would be challenging as it requires two completely different ideas.

@Peterius I've seen the idea of "raising" a number to make a power used in a few puzzles on this Stack Exchange, so the idea immediately came to mind, but it never felt satisfying or fair to me. Power notation always has the power be written smaller, so a digit simply moved up and right doesn't look like an exponent.

@xnor So would you say the quiz is rather badly designed and is unlikely to be solved by people without a mathematical background?

@xnor On typewritten mathematics papers from a certain period, the power was often written the same size, just superscript.

I don't think this puzzle requires very exceptional (high) mathematical skill set. To use it at a, say recreational, puzzle party ... perhaps someone would potentially claim that: $\frac{42}{7}=6$$$\boxed4\boxed2$$$$\boxed 7$$$$\boxed=$$$$\boxed6$$somehow also counts as solution. :) So be prepared to have a counter argument ready (like: requiring 100% correct syntax ... missing horizontal division line).

@FirstNameLastName Cool division!  Another possibility is: $$\boxed4 \boxed2 \ = \ \boxed6 \ \ \boxed7$$ where there is an assumed multiplication on the right hand side.

In every case (power, division, multiplication) some flexibility is to be allowed or forbidden. Agreed, power (albeit not perfect) is closest to, or even, correct expression.

Unsure about how "high-mathy" is

 programming in C++ (and some other languages which allow this syntax),

but in this case you only need

 to turn the "=" card 90°, making the result looks like 46 || 72. The || is the logical (short-circuit) OR operator in C++ (and many languages of the C family including C itself), and both sides are true (nonzero). So, the result is true (i.e. correct) as well.


Julia, Python and Haskell (and probably others) seem not happy with 46 || 72. Perl gives me 46 (and 72 for 72||42). C(++) and bc (and probably others) give us 1. But is 1 true? I feel like || result correctness enters a grey zone. I would prefer to get true rather than $1$

@FirstNameLastName C indeed gives 1 (as int), but C++ gives bool (and usually outputs true as 1).

OK fair enough!
